# Using @WebFilter and @WebListener vs <filter> and <listener> in web.xml (Jersy2 with Servlet 3.x)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0, java-melody, servlet-3.1

I am trying to use `java-melody` in an web application for monitoring purposes.

**Dependency in build.gradle**

```
compile group: 'net.bull.javamelody', name: 'javamelody-core', version: '1.69.0'
```

**With web.xml (Works Fine)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**Application init class**

```
@ApplicationPath(value = "/*")
public class TestJavamelodyApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public TestJavamelodyApp() {
        packages("com.test.resources")
                .register(CustomWebExceptionMapper.class)
                .register(new TestCustomBinder())
    }
}
```

It works as expected till here.

But i do not want to use the `web.xml` since we can do that in `Servlet 3.x`. So i did like below, which does not seem to work...

**The Filter**

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC})
public class JavaMelodyMonitoringFilter extends MonitoringFilter {
}
```

**Modified Application init**

```
@ApplicationPath(value = "/*")
public class TestJavamelodyApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public TestJavamelodyApp() {
        packages("com.test.resources")
                .register(CustomWebExceptionMapper.class)
                .register(new TestCustomBinder())
                .register(MonitoringFilter.class)
                .register(SessionListener.class);
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong here? Aren't both same?

**What Does not Work**

With `web.xml`, i can access the resource at `http://localhost:8080/test-app/monitoring` and all graphs show up fine. But without any `web.xml` and with `@WebFilter`, that resource is not accessible.

Comment: What does not work? What's the expected output vs the actual output?

Comment: @NexusDuck : Added in the question.